# why it can add active to the a label?

Tags: javascript

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="/about/">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/archives/">Our Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="/free/">Free Stuff</a></li>
</ul>
```

js code:

```
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) {
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}
```

i can't understand it well.
1, first `aObj` is get all the a label in nav

2,`aObj.length` equals 4,

3,`document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href` what's this line meanig?

4,why the loop can add `active` to the current a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3,document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href
>   what's this line meanig?

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0)
```

it is checking if the `href` of `<a>` tag is a part of `href` of current page. if the `indexOf` method returns greater than or equal to 0 then we know this is the current page and needs to be of active class.

> 4,why the loop can add active to the
>   current a?

```
aObj[i].className='active';
```

`<a>` tag have the property `ClassName` which can be retrieved and can be set using javascript. It is setting the `active` class to current page link.

Comment: why should use the loop? could i delete the for loop, make the if directly?

Comment: @zhuanzhou: you have to compare every `<a>` tag `href` with current page url in order to determine which `<a>` is active hence loop needed here